# Probability of winner in random seeding knockout tournament?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a knockout tournament with $2^n$ competitors, I know the pairwise probabilities of victory for each competitor vs. all other competitors. Given these probabilities, and seedings assigned randomly, what is the probability that any one competitor wins the entire tournament?

This question is directly asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1723858/691023

I can't comment on the old post because I have insufficient reputation points. Therefore, I am making a new post.

The best answer is certainly the second answer from `theseadroid`, however it gives the wrong answer. The reasoning is correct, but the outside coefficient in $P_{r+1}(i,!j)$ is incorrect. I convinced myself of this by running a tournament with a hegemon - that is, a player who beats all other players head-to-head. The hegemon should win $100\%$ of the time.

However, with this coefficient ($\frac{2^n−2^r}{2^n−1}$), their "probability" of winning drops every round after the second round, coincidentally right when that bottom equation is employed and the coefficient comes into play.

What is the correct coefficient? Thank you!

Comment: It is OK (in my book) to give an answer that is not much more than a long comment, when the comment is a significant contribution (as yours seems to be), although it's best to announce upfront and clearly that that's what you're doing.  In this case, I would suggest including an explicit counterexample to the answer you say is incorrect, say with $n=3$ (or maybe just $n=2$, if that's easier and suffices), carrying out the other answer's calculations all the way to the (incorrect) final result. (I had a hard time following some of that answer's notation, so I'd like to see this anyway).

Comment: I think there is a serious flaw in the linked answer.  It says that the probability that $i$ beats $j$ in round $r$ is $P_r,(!j, i)P_v(i,j)P_r(j)$  but this is treating the events $E_1 = j$ gets to round $r$ and $E_2 = i$ gets to round $r$ without having met $j$ as independent, and they most certainly are not.  If $i$ is certain to beat $j$, for example, then $j$ chances of reaching round $r$ are obviously not independent of meeting $i$ in an earlier round.

Comment: Actually, my previous comment is not quite correct, though the error doesn't change the thrust.  The linked answer correctly weights the factor noted in my previous comment by the probability that $i$ and $j$ meet in round $r$ if they both get there.  (When I say "correctly," I mean it is correct to weight by that probability, not that the weight has been computed correctly.)  As I said, though, if my comment about independence is correct, the weighting doesn't help matters.

Comment: This post appears to be close to a solution:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3233970/691023

@saulspatz

Comment: Perhaps, but at first glance, that question seems a lot simpler, because the higher-ranked player always beats the lower-ranked player.   Once you establish the bracket, the outcome of the tournament is determined.  In your question, for each bracket, we have $2^n-1$ matches, with two possible outcomes for each.  I'll look at the answer more closely though.