# Probability of a team winning in round $r$ of a simple single elimination tournament?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $2^n$ teams in a single elimination tournament. Each team in each match $v$ has an equal probability $P_v(i, j) = 1/2$ of winning the match. What's the probability that a team wins in round $r$?

The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819314/probability-of-team-winning-in-a-single-elimination-tournament) suggests that the probability would be a recursive formula. In our simple case, this recursive formula yields, for the probability that team $i$ wins round $r$,

$$P_{r}(i)=P_{r-1}(i)\frac{1}{2^{n-r+1}-1}\sum_{j\ne i}P_v(i,j)P_{r-1}(j) =  P_{r-1}(i) \frac{1}{2^{n-r+1}-1} (2^{n-r+1}-1)\cdot(1/2 \cdot P_{r-1}(i)) $$

since all the probabilities are uniform.
Then, we can cancel and rearrange to get $P_r(i) = \frac 1 2 (P_{r-1}(i))^2$, with $P_1(i) = \frac 1 2$. We can unroll the recursion and get a simple formula, $P_r(i) = \frac 1 {2^{2^{r} - 1}}$.

But there is another line of thinking which yields a different answer. Look at round $r$: how could team $i$ (WLOG) have gotten to round $r$? Well, it would have had to have won rounds $1, 2, \ldots, r-1$, so the probability that it wins round $r$ is $\frac{1}{2^r}$.

Which answer for "what is the probability that team $i$ wins round $r$"? Is it the first formula, or the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in replacing the sum by $2^{n-r+1}-1$ times the constant summand. The sum is still over all other teams, including all the ones that have been eliminated, so the sum is $2^n-1$ times the constant summand, independent of $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking "simple single elimination tournament" to be a knockout tournament, it is obvious that to win round $r$ it has to play $r$ matches, winning each wuth $Pr= \frac12$, thus P(win round $r = \frac{1}{2^r}$

and thus the second formula is correct